# Colorbrewer is not defined with angularjs and d3

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, d3.js, colorbrewer

I am trying to apply gradient colors to the slices of sunburst chart. With reference to the  answers on this [`question`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37241610/how-to-transform-the-following-d3-sunburst-graph-to-support-gradient-colors) , i did some research and started to use the [`colorbrewer`](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/5577023) within my code.

**Note:** I have referenced both d3 and colorbrewer in my app

**Code:**

```
  var path = g.append("path")
            .attr("d", arc)
            .style("fill", function(d) {
              var colorPicked =  color((d.children ? d : d.parent).name);
              console.log("ColorPicked",colorPicked)
              return d3.scale.quantize().range(colobrewer.OrRd[8]).domain([0, 16000]);
            })
            .on("click", click);
```

It says colobrewer  is not defined. Probably i am missing something here. How can i apply the gradient to the slices?

[`Full Application`](http://jsfiddle.net/sajeetharan/wjaaw340/2/)

Comment: Ok, second try: maybe `colorbrewer` insted of `colobrewer`?

Comment: yes!now there is no error ! but gradient is not applied

Comment: do you want something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/tpbp8rs1/

Comment: @GerardoFurtado No, already i have that one , i want something like mentioned here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37241610/how-to-transform-the-following-d3-sunburst-graph-to-support-gradient-colors

Comment: This is very cool application!

Comment: The thing is with this you wont get it how you want it to look as you haven't got as many sections. I.e not enough data so it will never look like the example you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returning a function:

```
return d3.scale.quantize().range(colobrewer.OrRd[8]).domain([0, 16000]);
```

you must return a color:

```
return colorPicked
```

If you want change color scale. Change here:

```
83      var color = d3.scale.category10();
```

From D3 [Wiki](https://github.com/d3/d3/wiki/Quantitative-Scales):

> ## d3.scale.quantize()
>
> Constructs a new quantize scale with the default domain [0,1] and the
>   default range [0,1]. Thus, the default quantize scale is equivalent to
>   the round function for numbers; for example quantize(0.49) returns 0,
>   and quantize(0.51) returns 1.

```
var q = d3.scale.quantize().domain([0, 1]).range(['a', 'b', 'c']); 
//q(0.3) === 'a', q(0.4) === 'b', q(0.6) === 'b', q(0.7) ==='c'; 
//q.invertExtent('a') returns [0, 0.3333333333333333]
```

> ## quantize(x)
>
> Given a value x in the input domain, returns the corresponding value
>   in the output range.

Replace your color definition:

```
var color = d3.scale.category10();
```

by

```
  var color=d3.scale.quantize()
            .range(colorbrewer.OrRd[8])
            .domain([0, 160]);
```

then assign the colors by "value" not "name":

```
  var path = g.append("path")
    .attr("d", arc)
    .style("fill", function(d) {
      var colorPicked =  color((d.children ? d : d.parent).value);
      return colorPicked
    })
    .on("click", click);
```

Comment: I know it should return a color, can you modify the plunker and show the o/p

Comment: still you dint get my question, you have posted the same fiddle which i posted as question

Comment: He hasn't shown the same fiddle, he's returned a different colour when filling in your arcs.

Comment: @thatOneGuy No its the same ! here i have added more data and it still behaves the same http://jsfiddle.net/sajeetharan/wjaaw340/7/

Comment: Maybe you can clarify what are you trying to achieve. From this side we answered your question. Now you are using colorbrewer and has no errors. :)